# Open port 1433 to use SSMS securely

Tags: sql-server, security

I have a SQL Server placed in DMZ and I want to give access to internal users (and VPN clients) to use SSMS to remotely connect to it via port 1433 so server will accept the connection only form defined IP sources over this port, is it a safe approach for a production server?

Comment: you will probably get a better answer at http://dba.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, locking down access to TCP 1443 from only certain trusted source IPs is a good move.

If the server is in a DMZ it is better to apply these rules to the border firewalls rather than on the server itself.